# Impala: how to create a materialized view in impala?

Tags: analytics, impala, bigdata

Can we create Materialized views in Impala?
If not, what is the alternative solution for better performance of view.

Answer (score 3):

Impala can't create materialized views at this time. So the solution for better view performance would be to load the output of the view query into a table and then have the view query the table or just query the table. As for keeping the data up to date you can take a batch approach of scheduling some DML statement to refresh the data or you could take a streaming approach by using something like Kafka to keep the data up to date.